# Is there a way to iterate over an object without the use of Object.keys(), Object.values() and object.entries() classes?

Tags: javascript

This is the code I used, however, I keep getting syntax error.

```
function iterateOverObject(obj) {
  foreach (const value in obj[key, value]) {
  console.log(obj[value]);
}
}
```

Comment: There is no `foreach` in javascript.

Comment: It's `for (const key in obj)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function iterateOverObject(obj) {
    for (const key in obj) {
    console.log(obj[key]);
  }
}
```